# Dont understand why this javascript won't work in jQm

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Seems to me like this should work (based on answers to other questions here on SM), but I'm not getting any results...

Here's my code in the head of the page:

Second edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function capitalizeFirstLetter(string){
            return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
        }


        $(document).delegate('#sun, #mon, #tue, #wed, #thu, #fri, #sat', 'pageshow' , function() { 
            var days   = ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'],
                output = [],//create an output buffering variable
                d = new Date();
            for(var x=0; x<days.length; x++){
                //rather than manipulate the DOM every iteration of the loop we add a string of HTML to an array
                output.push('<li><a href="#' + days[x] + '">' + capitalizeFirstLetter(days[x]) + '</a></li>');
            }

            //now we add the buffered data to the listview and either refresh or initialize the widget
            var $cNav = $('#custom-navbar')
            $cNav.append(output.join(''));

            //if the listview has the `ui-listview` class then it's been initialized, and the widget needs to be refreshed, otherwise it needs to be initialized
            if ($cNav.hasClass('ui-navbar')) {
                $cNav.navbar('refresh');
            } else {
                $cNav.navbar();
            }
        });

    </script>
```

And here's my code in the body:

```
<div data-role="content">
<div data-role="navbar" style="margin: -10px 0 15px 0;">
    <ul id="custom-navbar"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Revision: `.live()` does work, but `.listview()` does not, so my original comments still holds: If people were following the [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery), they'd notice: *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."* (with example).

Comment: @FelixKling i would imagine that `.listview()` is part of the jquery-mobile library ... its above the `<script>` tag that adds the library

Comment: @ManseUK: You are right. You still have to put the call in the ready handler. And then the order does not matter anymore (as `. listview` is executed when the DOM is loaded, i.e. all scripts are loaded). But I agree including them in the order of dependence makes more sense.

Comment: @ManseUK, I've tried moving the script around all over the place (and tried again after your comments), but to no avail. My code still isn't rendering. I'm not even getting the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).delegate('#sun', 'pageshow' , function() { 
        alert("!");
        var days   = ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','fri','sat'],
            output = [];//create an output buffering variable
        for(var x=0; x<days.length; x++){
            alert(days[x]);

            //rather than manipulate the DOM every iteration of the loop we add a string of HTML to an array
            output.push('<li><a data-ajax="false" href="#' + days[x] + '">' + days[x] + '</a></li>');
        }

        //now we add the buffered data to the listview and either refresh or initialize the widget
        var $cNav = $('#custom-navbar')
        $cNav.append(output.join(''));

        //if the listview has the `ui-listview` class then it's been initialized, and the widget needs to be refreshed, otherwise it needs to be initialized
        if ($cNav.hasClass('ui-listview')) {
            $cNav.listview('refresh');
        } else {
            $cNav.listview();
        }
    });

</script>
<script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
```

Since this code runs each `pageshow` event, you will be getting multiple listings when users navigate to, away, and then back to the page. You could use the `pageinit` event instead: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

## Update

The error in your page comes from here:

```
                $('ul#custom-navbar').append('<li/>', {
                    .append('<a/>', {
                        'href' = "#" + days[x],
                        'data-ajax' = "false",
                        'text' = days[x]
                    });
                });
```

Do you see it? You've got an extra `, {` and are missing a bit of syntax to make this make sense. You're also using equal signs where you should be using colons (since you're setting properties of an object):

```
                $('ul#custom-navbar').append(
                    $('<li/>').append('<a/>', {
                        'href'      : "#" + days[x],
                        'data-ajax' : "false",
                        'text'      : days[x]
                    })
                );
```

This creates a list-item, then appends a link to it with some attributes set.

Note that you can copy my code, paste it over your code (in your document) and it will work fine. I've tested it using my console.

In a general sense, you should learn to use your console, it will help you an amazing amount. For instance I found the error on your page in about 30 seconds...

Comment: @JustinWhite do you have a link to the page in question?

Comment: @JustinWhite See the **update** to my answer. You've got a parse error happening, but you can fix it by simply pasting my code over your existing code.

Comment: @JustinWhite If you watch your console, all JS errors will display and you will be given a line number for each error. You can use multiple selectors at once just by deliminating them with a comma: `$('#sun, #mon, #tue, #wed, #thu, #fri, #sat')...`.

Comment: Ok, so I've updated my post with the current code. I've got the navbar showing whenever the page loads, but it only shows with the first page in the doc. When navigating to the other pages the navbar disappears and stays gone forever and ever. I've tried with data-ajax="true" and data-ajax="false". Do I need to you trigger() or destroy() or anything like that to reload the navbar each time a link is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the jQuery Mobile website they directly recommend *not* binding to $(document).ready() due to their use of some ajax magic behind the scenes and instead recommend performing something similar to what you're doing but with pageinit instead of pageshow.  From what I can see in the documentation they should be (for this) functionally equivalent.  Have you tried binding pageshow or pageinit *after* loading jqm?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

> Important: Use pageInit(), not $(document).ready()
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'pageshow' event is of jquery mobile framework. If am right, then you should add jquery mobile script tag before your script.

Comment: That should not matter. You can even define your own events with jQuery, they don't have to "exist". E.g. I can say `$('#foo').bind('bar', ....)`. `bar` is not a defined event. Still, the event handler is executed whenever I call `$('#foo').trigger('bar')`.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly use

`$('ul#custom-navbar').listview();`

not `$('ul#custom-navbar').listview('refresh');` this won't work if the element isn't initialized

**But** If you added the html attr data-role="listview" on the ul, the on pageshow jQM will automatically init the listview, if so and then you added elements to it, then you would need to run `$('ul#custom-navbar').listview('refresh');` I recommend you do this instead.

**Also** you need to put the `$('ul#custom-navbar').listview();` within your live function like someone else mentioned, jQM isn't loaded when you call it, and you should be using the pageinit event, pageshow also fires when you navigate back to the page (thru the back button etc), you don't want to init it twice. Read up on those two, optimally you'd be using both to cleanly handle JS.

**PS:** I'm glad you are properly listening to the pageinit/pageshow events and not using document.ready, also I suggest starting those listeners in the mobileinit handler, e.g.
`$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){//your pageinit/pageshow listeners here` and also the `.live` function is deprecated now, use `$(document).on('pageinit pageshow', 'div:jqmData(role="page"), div:jqmData(role="dialog")', function(oEvent){`